# Classifying 64x4 images representing piano rolls as real or fake

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, music-notation

I want to build a GAN for generating piano rolls (what I'll describe differs from real piano rolls but can be thought of as a variant of them). Thus my first problem is that I need a discriminator network that can tell if a piano roll is real or fake.

A piano roll is a 2d matrix so it can be visualized as an image. But it doesn't look at all like images of faces, cats and dogs so "normal" deep learning techniques for classifying images would be unlikely to work. So I need advice on what could work and what researchers have tried.

The format of my data is 64x4 matrices so that there are 64 time steps and at most four notes can be played simultaneously. Each non-zero cell represents the onset of a note and the integer value the pitch of the note. So 1 is the lowest note and 48 is the highest note (four octaves in total).

Below are examples of how these "piano rolls" look like. You'll have to zoom in using an image viewer that doesn't blur pixels to see them. Each rectangle is a piano roll. Each pixel represents the onset of a note. I've color coded them so that shades of red are for C notes in different octaves, green for D notes and so on. Gray is the background color and represents the lack of notes. The network should classify them as "real".

[image]

Below are examples of "fake" piano rolls. These are randomly generated and then color coded using the scheme described above. The network should classify them as "fake".

[image]

Comment: This seems like a normal image classification problem with your images. "Normal" image classification can identify faces, trains, dogs, burritos, oil paintings, species of trees, etc. You can likely use an existing architecture, you just can't use pre-trained weights. Regardless, this is likely a better question for [datascience.se] than for stack overflow, as it's a tutorial or library request without a [mcve]

Comment: I second G. Anderson's note. Just train up a simple network with some convolutions for binary classification and I bet you'll get very good accuracy with very little training. Do you have a function that plays these piano rolls? If so, can you share it? Also, where does this groundtruth data come from?

Comment: @Björn Lindqvist if you want to collaborate on this and you have some training data hit me up: douglas.duhaime@gmail.com. I'm keen on this idea